# Fetch data from Mongoose and put into an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need an array of a collection on the front end to render a chart. I would use toArray method from mongo but Mongoose doesn't has it (I guess).

I've created an script tag with an array inside of it on my EJS view.This is the array that I want to "feed".

On my route I have the collection.find() to find the data and send it to the front end.

The database model is this one if anyone is interested:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('atendimento', {
    id: String,
    id_atendimento: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    id_cliente: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    id_user: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    user_nome: String,
    cliente_nome: String,
    id_atendente: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    atendente_nome: String,
    atendente_imagem: String,
    setor: Number,
    descricao: String,
    status: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    inicio: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    fim: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    update: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

I won't be using all this fields but this is not important at the moment, I just want to know how to take the objects and put them into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data is just send to front end for rendering then have a look at [lean](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)

```
db.collection.find().lean().exec((err, docs)=>{console.log(docs)})
```

lean method returns plain javascript objects, not MongooseDocuments.

Comment: Hmm, I see. So, suppose that I want to use it as JSON data, after executing the query with lean, I have to parse it to JSON? Also, this lean method put the objects into an array? Because this is what I need. Anyway, I'll check it out, thank you!

Comment: Yes, the output will still remain as an Array after lean method. Also no need to parse it to JSON. It can be used as normal Object data. You can access keys from the Object such as docs[0].id etc.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'll test using it on ChartJS, it'll be easier to filter if I can use docs[0].databasefield. If I do a foreach using docs.length it will work as well, right?

Comment: Yes any Array method like map, foreach, etc.. will work